# Is there any decent way/plugin to show SVG images?

Tags: nativescript

Long ago I searched on Internet for a SVG image plugin and found [that one](https://github.com/peoplewareDo/nativescript-svg), which is almost broken, outdated and thus unusable. Is there any other plugin that I might miss that allows to show SVG images and works fine with recent Nativescript version?

Comment: Did you ever figure something out?

Comment: Nope, I abandoned that idea.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still struggling with this, there is another route you could take. What ended up doing was converting my svg files into a font file (.tff). My svg files were simple, so I'm not sure if this will work for every case, but at least it works for using icons. It's really easy to convert svg files to a .ttf file. I used [this](https://glyphter.com/) online tool converter, then I added the file into my nativescript app/fonts folder. Now I can use a label like this to display the svg files:

```
<label
  style="font-family: yourFontFileName;"
  text="A" //This will show the icon mapping to the letter 'A'
></label>
```

It's also worth noting that since it's a font, you can change stroke color, and size.

**Note**: Android uses the file name as the font name, while IOS has its own font name. To find the font name you can just open your .ttf file, and it should open a window showing the letters (icons) and the font name as the title

Comment: It wasn't displaying anything for me. It might be related to this: https://github.com/peoplewareDo/nativescript-svg/issues/24

Comment: **Note:** This works for simple, single-colored svg-files. It does not work for more complex icons using multiple colors (as the conversion to a font removes the colors).

Comment: I had a similar issue where my font library didn't have what I needed. I combined SVGs and followed the process from this answer except I used icomoon to do the conversion, which worked better for me since I could specify a unicode character for the glyphs. Thanks for posting your solution!

Answer (score 1):

There is an updated fork from [teammaestro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@teammaestro/nativescript-svg)

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
      xmlns:svg="@teammaestro/nativescript-svg" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
    <svg:SVGImage src="~/image/nativescript.svg" height="100" />
    <svg:SVGImage src="https://media4.giphy.com/media/3uyIgVxP1qAjS/200.svg" height="200" />
    <svg:SVGImage src="res://somesvg" height="200" />
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: Do you know where the best place to store an svg image is for nativescript? I'm guessing android-drawable-nodpi, but I don't know where in IOS, anywhere?

Comment: Every where that I look, it seems that svg are usually first converted to pdf and store in assets.xcassets for ios since it doesn't directly support svg files.